# Meteor App Deploy, but page is blank: ServiceConfiguration is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, deployment

Recently moved to Meteor 1.4 and am using Kadirahq/mup to deploy. The deploy is successful but after browsing to page the page is blank and there is only 1 error in the console. The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined
```

Building and deploying from ubuntu 14.04 on to ubuntu 14.04. We have added Service-Configuration but the error is still present.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like several people have had this same issue for different reasons.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3506

Most of them are related to the packages they are using in their project. Can you post the contents of your packages file?

Comment: we have discovered that if you deploy in "DEBUG" mode everything works

Comment: I would still check on your packages. One way, although very tedious, is to remove your packages one at a time and see if the error stops. Or you could remove every package that is not critical (i.e., won't stop your app from loading), and then add them back one by one to see if the error comes back. The second option would obviously assume that removing the packages eliminates the error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can appear after deploying an application to production when you misspell your helpers template name. 
The application runs fine on the development machine.

Something like:

```
<template name="customers">
...
</template>
```

In js: notice the misspelled templatename for helper functions.

```
Template.custmers.helpers({
...
});
```